# How to catch errors in postgresql function if using union query inside to know which part of union gave the error

Tags: postgresql, function

I am trying to build a Testing function which I will integrate with circle CI. Idea is to build a 1 master test function which will execute number of underlying functions with parameter and show result as which one passed and which one failed .

Currently I have the function prototype which calls 3 functions and testes them.According to my logic I am seeing result pass/fail if underlying function is not returning  any data. But when there is syntax error in underlying functions it just show what error is according to my logic because I am catching exception but it will not show which function the error came from.

Here is my test function prototype :

```
RETURNS table (function text, result text) AS $$
  DECLARE cnt  INTEGER;
BEGIN

    return query

    select 'org.fn_get_org_hierarchy_full'::text as function,
           case when count(*) > 0 then 'pass'::text else 'fail'::text end as result
    from org.fn_get_org_hierarchy_full(array['828a5368-c27b-4cf4-41bb-25eed0f50420'])

    UNION

    select 'assessment.fn_get_activity_summary'::text as function,
           case when count(*) > 0 then 'pass'::text else 'fail'::text end as result
    from assessment.fn_get_activity_summary('9144de83-e18e-9c8a-0051-b13eb4227d42', -- root_org_sk
                                            ARRAY ['40b4ae2c-aec7-c27c-7a39-616055d8c174'],
                                            ARRAY ['359f3a32-6ba5-a366-028a-df8c274f650c'],
                                             array['ND'], -- learner_sk
                                             ARRAY['ND'], -- status
                                             Array['ND'],
                                             ARRAY['ND'],
                                             ARRAY['ND'],
                                            '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
                                            '2999-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
                                              10000,0,
                                            array['ND']
                                            )

    UNION

     select 'assessment.fn_get_activity_details'::text as function,
           case when count(*) > 0 then 'pass'::text else 'fail'::text end as result
    from assessment.fn_get_activity_details('9144de83-e18e-9c8a-0051-b13eb4227d42',     
                                              array['40b4ae2c-aec7-c27c-7a39-616055d8c174'],  
                                              array['359f3a32-6ba5-a366-028a-df8c274f650c'],  
                                              array['ND'],  -- learner
                                              array['c9f84884-348e-5388-6e5e-4321526410d0'],  
                                              array['ND'],  -- assessment_sk
                                              array['ND'],  -- cls_term
                                              array['ND'],  -- cls_sys
                                              array['ND'],  -- assigned_item_status
                                              array['assessment'],  -- assignment_type_name
                                              '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', -- min_student_start_datetime
                                              '2999-01-01 00:00:00.000', -- max_student_stop_datetime,
                                            10000,0,
                                            array['ND']
                                            );


exception when others then

    raise notice 'Function Failed';

    raise notice '% % ', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;



END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have set it up with all the parameters underlying function needs.

Here is how I see the output :

[image]

If function dosent return data then I see fail in front of it which is what I want.

But if there is syntax error then I am seeing output as this : 
[image]

Is there a way I can show the output in exact same format like this even if syntax error. I mean is I want to see fail in front of function which has syntax error. I figure I will need some sort of try catch mechanism for each part of union I have . How can I better approach this? Or is there a way to do this in postgresql.

Comment: I just want to appreciate how you wrote array three different ways in three consecutive lines: "array", "ARRAY", "Array"

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: Don't worry I'm just having a bit of fun.

Comment: Try printing the call stack: see 43.6.9 in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING, if a function you're calling is raising the exception, you should be able to see which one in the call stack.

Comment: When you want to catch the exceptions of I'm afraid you'd need to leave the relational way and call each function individually with a catching block each. To add a row to the result you can use `RETURN NEXT`.

Comment: @404 no the function I am calling does not have exception block in them

Comment: @stickybit can you give me an example in my logic

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
I found a way to do it this way : let me know if any other efficient way :

```
RETURNS table (function text, result text) AS $$
  DECLARE cnt  INTEGER;
BEGIN


    begin
    return query

    select 'org.fn_get_org_hierarchy_full'::text as function,
           case when count(*) > 0 then 'pass'::text else 'fail'::text end as result
    from org.fn_get_org_hierarchy_full(array['828a5368-c27b-4cf4-41bb-25eed0f50420']);


    exception when others then

    raise notice 'Error  : org.fn_get_org_hierarchy_full failed';

    raise notice '% % ', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;

    End;


    BEGIN

    return query
    select 'assessment.fn_get_activity_summary'::text as function,
           case when count(*) > 0 then 'pass'::text else 'fail'::text end as result
    from assessment.fn_get_activity_summary('9144de83-e18e-9c8a-0051-b13eb4227d42', -- root_org_sk
                                            ARRAY ['40b4ae2c-aec7-c27c-7a39-616055d8c174'],
                                            ARRAY ['359f3a32-6ba5-a366-028a-df8c274f650c'],
                                             array['ND'], -- learner_sk
                                             ARRAY['ND'], -- status
                                             Array['ND'],
                                             ARRAY['ND'],
                                             ARRAY['ND'],
                                            '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
                                            '2999-01-01 00:00:00.000000',
                                              10000,0,
                                            array['ND']
                                            );


    exception when others then

    raise notice 'Error : assessment.fn_get_activity_summary Failed';

    raise notice '% % ', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
   end;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Each query has its individual `begin` and `end` block 
and catch exception.